# Rename ambiguous [sf] and [sp]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, blocklist-request

I've encountered two tags used for R libraries: [sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sf) and [sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sp).

Both has tag info and a significant number of questions and watchers.

But both had questions erroneously using these tags. Most likely due to ambiguity of two-letter abbreviations.

Cases of ambiguous use I've encountered:

- sf: Salesforce and Terraform's statefile,
- sp: SharePoint, stored procedures (many of them), scalable pixels, stack pointer, stochastic programming, service provider, and service principal.

All of the questions erroneously using this tags have been retagged in accordance with their content (except for [this gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646014)). Check links: [sf](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsf%5D%20%20collective%3A-%22R%20Language%22%20is%3Aq%20-spatial%20-%5Br-leaflet%5D%20-%5Bspatial%5D%20-%5Bcoordinates%5D%20-%5Binstall.packages%5D%20-%5Bshapefile%5D&searchOn=3), [sp](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsp%5D%20%20collective%3A-%22R%20Language%22%20is%3Aq%20-spatial%20-%5Bspatial%5D)

To prevent future confusion over them, I propose to rename these tags into [r-sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-sf) and [r-sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-sp) accordingly, and add [sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sf) and [sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sp) into stop list.

---

Additional information: it seems that there are quite a bit of tags for R packages that don't use convention of `r-library`. A couple of examples: [spatstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spatstat), [maptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maptools), [forestplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forestplot), [rgdal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rgdal). It might be beneficial to rename those into [r-spatstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-spatstat), etc. too. Most of them seems to have something like "R package" in their tag info, but I don't know how to search through it.

Comment: I haven't found better way to search in tag info than SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1775478. Looks like there is a couple more good candidates for re-tagging.

Comment: Classic ambiguity with TLA (Two letter acronym, not to be confused with [TLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym) though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sp) is now [r-sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-sp), no synonym
- [sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sf) is now [r-sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-sf), no synonym

  - I note the existence of a very unclear [rsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsf) tag that has some issues, but is ostensibly unrelated.  Could use some cleanup.
- [maptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maptools) is now [r-maptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-maptools), with a synonym, after removing a couple questions that were clearly unrelated to R.
- [forestplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forestplot) is now [r-forestplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-forestplot), no synonym, as the *vast* majority of the questions were about the R package.  Someone should probably clean up [the remaining ones not tagged with [r]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-forestplot+-r).  Maybe a new [forest-plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forest-plots) tag would be good here?

I didn't do anything with:

- [spatstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spatstat), because the name seems pretty unique.
- [rgdal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rgdal), because as far as I can tell, the "r" stands for R already.

Comment: I'm on the fence about that [sp] synonym.  I could probably be convinced to remove it if anyone feels strongly.

Comment: I'm not sure in synonym for [sp]. I've seen quite a bit of questions about stored procedures tagged with [sp], and I have my doubts, that people who used it will notice [r-sp] and will correct it. But I'm not heavily invested in problem to be more convincing :-)

Comment: Cleaned up the remaining ones, where was possible. Couple were already in collective, and I decided not to touch them. And one had 5 tags, and it seems very clear it's about R already, so I left it as is too.

Comment: Also I've created [tag:forest-plots], and partially copied it's excerpt and wiki from original one. As usual it requires some reviews)

Comment: @markalex Thanks!  Approved those with some edits (don't forget that usage guidance), and also removed the [sp] synonym.

Comment: "r" definitely stands for R :)

Comment: @RyanM, may I ask, why [tag:sf] retagging was reverted?

Comment: @markalex Uhhhhh.  Good question.  It's... possible I screwed up?  Or that the rename failed and I failed to check that it had actually worked?  Anyway, it's fixed now.  Thanks for catching it.